# Spring AOPed target class not injecting mocks

Tags: spring, mockito, aop, spring-aop

I have class A having structure:

```
@Service
Class A implements AInterface {

  private final C c;
  String test(String b) {
   }
}
```

Structure of class C:

```
class C {
  // some methods
}
```

then I wrote interceptor for this class :

```
@Aspect
@Component
class Interceptor {
  @Around(
  value =
      "execution(* AInterface.test(..)) && args(c)")
   public Object intercept(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, String c) {
      // some logic
   }
 
}
```

I am trying to do integration test and wants to inject mock class c in A but its not happening.
Test class structure:

```
 @SpringBootTest 
 class ATest {
     // Tried @MockBean also
    @Mock
    private C c;
    @Autowired @InjectMock private AInterface a;

    @BeforeTest {
     MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
     // tried using ReflectionUtils to inject mock
    }

   @Test
    void testTest () {

    // when then logic
    }
   
    

    }
```

Comment: What does not work ? What is the error ? Where are you injecting mock object to class A?

Comment: Updated the code to use inject mock annotations for class under test

Comment: What error do you get ?  Is reference variable c null ? Could you please share a git project that reproduces this issue ?

Comment: The object c is the real object instead of mock.  I have to create the project. I will share it here as soon as possible.